# Hide parent if child is empty

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide the parent `li` if child `li` is empty. Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nepfw2qf/6/) where I want to hide the parent `li` label TWO.

```
<ul id='ListNav'>
    <li ng-repeat='mainList in lists.list' ng-hide='subList.length<0' >
        <a>{{mainList.label}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='subList in mainList.subList'>{{subList.label}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem just change:

```
<li ng-repeat='mainList in lists.list' ng-hide='subList.length<0' >
```

To

```
<li ng-repeat='mainList in lists.list' ng-show="mainList.subList.length>0" >
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nepfw2qf/8/)

Comment: Thank you It works and now I know why the same thing didn't work for me when I trying. The reason is becuase my subList is also filtered and it get filter after MainList ng-hide is called. Liked this - <li ng-repeat='subList in mainList.subList  | filter:{group:groupNum}'>{{subList.label}}</li>

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `subList` at that level try changing it for `mainList.subList`

```
<ul id='ListNav'>
        <li ng-repeat='mainList in lists.list' ng-hide='mainList.subList.length==0'> <a>{{mainList.label}}</a>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat='subList in mainList.subList'>{{subList.label}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nepfw2qf/7/

Comment: Thanks rdz. Your response is almost same as above. I guess you both replied at same time but I didn't mention here that my sublist is also filtered and that is why it didn't work for me. Like this -  <li ng-repeat='subList in mainList.subList | filter:{group:groupNum}'>{{subList.label}}</li>

Comment: Hmmm, looks like its complex. Still looking for solution how to run ng-hide after sublist filter is applied.

Comment: it is not complex, what you asked is solved here, now i dont understand what you mean with your filter, maybe you should try to update your question or make a new one

Comment: Thanks for response - The question is - The ng-hide is running before the the filter is a applied to subList. So there is always some li in subList so mainlist is not hiding. check this jsfiddle I updated show the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/nepfw2qf/9/